# Set row index with ag-grid in Angular

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am trying to create a table with ag-grid in Angular.
Is there a way to **set the row index** at this time?

Other than that I create a seq column and use a function to change the value. I'm sure it can be set as an option, but it doesn't seem to exist when I searched the documentation...

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UU7K.png)

Comment: My reputation is not enough to post image directly.. Forgive me!!!

Comment: Rather than posting an image of your table (which is relatively simple), you can add that table directly as formatted text. See [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/616624) for more information.